# Calculating individual predicted probability from logistic model and 95% confidence interval for shiny app

Tags: r, logistic, confidence-interval, predictive-models, risk

I have developed a logistic model to predict the risk of an outcome (TRS) based on some predictors. This was developed on a number of imputed datasets generated by mice (imp2) as follows:

```
mod<-expression(glm( outcome ~ 
                   age+sex+black_ethn+asian_ethn+
                   continuous1+continuous2
                 , family =  "binomial", x=TRUE,y=TRUE))
analyse<-with(imp2, mod)
mice::pool(analyse)
```

Then I took the coefficients, and I have developed a [shiny app](https://eosimo.shinyapps.io/trs_app/) that outputs the risk of developing an outcome (TRS) based on these predictor variables. This is what it does:

```
function(age+sex+black_ethn+asian_ethn+continuous1+continuous2){
    return(exp((-2.827381 +  #intercept
                (ifelse(sex=="Male",0.286466741, 0))+ #sex
                (0.006713513*continuous1) + 
                (0.131215526*continuous2) + 
                (ifelse(ethnicity=="asian_ethn", -0.144147329, ifelse(ethnicity=="black_ethn", 0.419614174, 0))) + 
                (-0.036205346*age)))/(1+exp(-2.827381 +  #intercept
                                     (ifelse(sex=="Male",0.286466741, 0))+ #sex
                                     (0.006713513*continuous1) + 
                                     (0.131215526*continuous2) + 
                                     (ifelse(ethnicity=="asian_ethn", -0.144147329, ifelse(ethnicity=="black_ethn", 0.419614174, 0))) + 
                                     (-0.036205346*age))
}
```

This however only gives me a point estimate of this risk for the individual patient, and not a 95% confidence interval.
Any ideas on how to estimate the CI for each prediction, which should take into account larger CIs in the tails of the distributions?